# Sponsored tag icons always delivered using http

Tags: bug, sponsored-tags, ssl

Prevent attackers from embedding evil kittens as tag icons! *(Well, I faked that one... Really, GitHub doesn't sponsor the tag icon? Sorry for misusing your logo, fitted much too nice here.)*

[image: Evil kitten as tag icon]

When loading the Stackoverflow page using https, the **sponsored tag icons are fetched using http nonetheless**, breaking consistent encryption of the site.

[image: Missing https for sponsored tag icons]

Comment: +1 Kitten-in-the-middle attacks are one of the most serious threats on the modern Internet.